# Call out sentence according to input

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm new in developing Android application and currently I'm developing a android software that require user to input quite amount of data and save it on `sharedPreferences` as database. Here is example of my coding:

```
public static final String DEFAULT= "no data found";
```

Then:

```
protected void storeData(SharedPreferences.Editor editor, String key, EditText et) {
    String content = et.getText().toString();
    if ("".equals(content)) {
        editor.remove(key);
    } else {
        editor.putString(key, content);
    }
}
```

For saving of user input:

```
    public void OnClickSave(){
            button17=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);
            button17.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
                            gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gender);
                            age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
                            fruit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fab_fruit);
                            music = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fab_music);
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        storeData(editor,"name", name);
                        storeData(editor,"gender", gender);
                        storeData(editor,"age", age);
                        storeData(editor,"fruit", fruit);
                        storeData(editor,"music", music);
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity7.this, "Data was saved!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

For loading the data, I made it something like this:

```
public void OnClickLoad(){
            button38=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button38);
            button38.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", DEFAULT);
            String gender = sharedPreferences.getString("gender", DEFAULT);
            String age = sharedPreferences.getString("age", DEFAULT);
            String fruit = sharedPreferences.getString("fruit", DEFAULT);
            String music = sharedPreferences.getString("music", DEFAULT);
             }
                    }
            );
AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity12.this);
            a_builder.setMessage(
                    "Data 1 name is :"+ name + "\n"+ 
                    "Data 1 gender is :"+ gender + "\n"+ 
                    "Data 1 age is :"+ age + "\n"+ 
                    "Data 1 favorite fruit is :"+ fruit + "\n"+ 
                    "Data 1 favorite music is :"+ music + "\n"+ 
)

                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Return", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            ;
            AlertDialog alert= a_builder.create();
            alert.setTitle("Checking");
            alert.show();
        }
```

As I already set the sentence in the builder, so when user didn't answer one of the question, the output will become like

```
                Data 1 name is : Sample1
                Data 1 gender is : male 
                Data 1 age is : no data found 
                Data 1 favorite fruit is : apple 
                Data 1 favorite music is : no data found
```

I wish to know if there are any alternative way , so that if user didn't input anything, the related sentences will not show up, like below:

```
        Data 1 name is : Sample1
        Data 1 gender is : Male
        Data 1 favorite fruit is : apple
```

This is example of coding, in my application I required user to input 20-30 data. Thank in advanced for anyone willing to help. 
*I'm sorry if the title cause any confusion because I'm not sure what should it refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a default `String` for your preferences, you could use `null` as the default value:

```
String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", null);
String gender = sharedPreferences.getString("gender", null);
// ...
```

After that, you could simply perform `null` value checks and construct your message accordingly:

```
StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

if(name != null) {
    messageBuilder.append("Data 1 name is: " + name);
    messageBuilder.append("\n");
}
if(gender != null) {
    messageBuilder.append("Data 1 gender is: " + gender);
    messageBuilder.append("\n");
}
// ...

a_builder.setMessage(messageBuilder.toString());
```